# Selenium-Xpath-Java or CSS locator

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Help me to find out the `xpath` for button "click for JS Alert"

Here is the link https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts

I am using this `xpath`-

```
.//*[@id='content']/div/ul/li[1]/button
```

and it showing no such element.

This is the code used:

```
public void test() { 
    driver.get("the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts");     
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("//button[text()='Click for JS Alert']")); 
    element.click(); 
}
```

Comment: What about `//button[text()='Click for JS Alert']`?

Comment: No it doesnt work.

Comment: I am writting this code

Comment: @Test
 public void test() {
   driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts");
   
   WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("//button[text()='Click for JS Alert']"));
   element.click();
  
 }

Answer (score 2):

You use code in a wrong way:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("//button[text()='Click for JS Alert']"));
```

`By.id` can be applied to search element with specified `id` attribute only while you use `XPath` instead.

You need to use below:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Click for JS Alert']")); 
element.click();
```

Comment: ohh that is blunder. i dont know how could i miss that but thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath: `(//div[@class='example']/ul/li/button)[1]`

Your code will be somewhat like this:

```
driver.get(""the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts");
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='example']/ul/li/button)[1]"));
element.click();
```

Comment: No it will select all the 3 button but i want to click only on one button.

Comment: @Test
 public void test() {
   driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts");
   
   WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("//button[text()='Click for JS Alert']"));
   element.click();
  
 }  my code,

Comment: It won't select all the 3 buttons. The `(//div[@class='example']/ul/li/button)` will fetch all the 3 buttons but since I am specifying the index of button `[1]` to be fetched, it will only fetch the first one.

Comment: see my updated answer. You can't use By.id if you are using the xpath to find the element

Answer (score 0):

//*[@id='content']/div/ul/li[1]/button works for me.  What browser are you using?  How are you validating?

Comment: Mozilla @Test
 public void test() {
   driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts");
   
   WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("//button[text()='Click for JS Alert']"));
   element.click();
  
 }

Comment: its working fine whn you write xpath in mozilla but when you use in code like driver.findElement(By.id("") it says that no such element found and am using implicit wait also

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Click for JS Alert')]")).click();
Thread.sleep(2500);
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
System.out.println(driver.switchTo().alert().getText());
alert.accept();
```

Comment: If this answer is `helpful` to you, then please mark this answer as `Accepted`.